# Given a quadratic equation, find values of $a$ such that the equation will have four different solutions.

Tags: quadratics, absolute-value

I was given this problem:

For what values of a, equation 
$2a(x + 1)^2 − | x + 1| + 1 = 0 $
has four different solutions?

Can someone tell me a way to start this problem. (I was thinking of discriminant, but it didn’t work)

Answer (score 0):

Hint

Assuming $x$ is real $$(x+1)^2=|x+1|^2$$

Again each non zero value of $y=|x+1|$ will corresponds to two distinct real values of $x$

So, how many distinct roots we need from $$2ay^2-y+2=0$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Split it into $x\ge-1$ and $x\lt-1$.  Use the quadratic formula.

Answer (score 0):

Let $t=|x+1|$.  Then $2a(x+1)^2-|x+1|+1=0\implies 2at^2-t+1=0$.

$t$ naturally has two real solutions, so if $2at^2-t+1=0$ has two distinct real solutions, then the original equation will have four distinct real solutions.

For $2at^2-t+1=0$, we have
\begin{align}
\Delta=(-1)^2-4(2a)(1)&>0\\
1-8a&>0\\
a&<\frac18
\end{align}

But, we also need to consider that if $a$ is negative, then the vertical reflection will *cancel out* the effect of the absolute value.

Therefore, we want $\boxed{0<a<\dfrac18}$.  What part of your solution using the discriminant did not work?

[Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rreff4ckmz) is a visual.

Answer (score 0):

$$
2au^2 = |u|-1\Rightarrow 2a|u|^2-|u|+1=0
$$

then

$$
|u|=\frac{1\pm \sqrt{1-8a}}{2a}
$$

so we choose $0 < a\lt \frac 18$